# How to filter Visual Studio 2008 output window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, outputdebugstring

I'm looking for a way to filter the messages coming out from OutputDebugString into the Output window in VS 2008. I'm modifying a large system and I'm only interested in my messages in the log.

I don't mind the output to be external to VS, in fact I would prefer if it would. Using SysInternals.DebugView I can easily filter the messages but when an app is being debugged in VS 2008 its output never reaches DebugView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found an interesting plugin to VS 2008: http://vsdbgview.codeplex.com/. Seems to be working for now.